# Rails: mysql load error when starting rails server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to migrate my rails application from rails version 3 to rails version 4.I have install mysql2 gem in my rails application and trying to run a rails server but I am getting below error.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.
0/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from E:/JCI-stable-final-Version-7-AoneSms/onspot-rails4.0.0/config/appl
ication.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Below is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'groupdate'
gem "chartkick"
gem "paperclip"
gem "easy_captcha"
gem "rails_email_validator"
gem "devise_security_extension"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "prawn-labels"
gem "rails-xmlrpc"
gem "rqrcode_png"
gem "rqrcode"
gem "blueprint-rails"
gem "mysql2" , "0.3.11"
gem "jeweler"
#gem "activesupport"
#gem "activerecord"
#gem "activerecord-import"
#gem "activerecord-mysql-adapter"
#gem "mysql"
gem "yaml_db"
gem "tabulous"
gem "thin"
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem "rake"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'




gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'


gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'fastercsv'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'

gem "devise"
#gem "devise", "~> 1.5.3"
#gem "orm_adapter", "~> 0.0.3"
gem 'json'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

#gem 'css-bootstrap-rails'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

gem 'impressionist'
gem 'devise-encryptable'
gem "devise_invitable"
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem uninstall mysql2

Download last MySQL connector from 
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip

Extract it to C:\connector-6.0.2

gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"'

If after installing the gem, you get an error:
"The specified module could not be found.
C:/Devel/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so"
Then copy  "libmysql.dll" to Ruby's bin folder.
```

**If still you are unable to fix this issue, have a look at this article:** 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798700/Install-Rails-and-MySQL-Server-on-Windows

Give a try, above trick might help. 
But truly, try moving to linux machine. Windows is never recommended for rails development.

Comment: Updated answer, I  did not notice you are hitting this error in windows. hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried it above command and gem is install sucesffully . but still getting same issue.. when i did bundle install i got   http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0
.2-win32.zip/from/pick

  And put lib\libmysql.dll file in your Ruby bin directory, for example C:\Ruby\
bin message

Comment: when i did bundle install i got below message

Comment: You are supposed to copy that libmysql.dll file to Ruby's bin folder. 
something similar to this :
i) Copy libmysql.dll from C:\Programs\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32\lib to C:\Programs\Ruby200\bin

Comment: Hi ajay i copied it to my ruby's bin folder (C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\bin) still getting same issue.i am running windows xp with 64 bit.

Comment: I just added an articles link in my answer, please follow that. And after you copy the required .dll file please open a new terminal shell and perform bundle. Thanks.

Comment: Hi after following your above instruction i did bundle update and its works for me... thanks